# Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4->5.8: SATA drives attached to Intel C602 "disappear"

Tags: drivers, hard-drive, hp, intel

I have a machine running Kubuntu 20.04, on an HP Z420, with 4 hard drives (in a software RAID configuration). Was working fine with 5.4.0 kernels, but after upgrade to 5.8.0-43-generic, it would fail to boot, only seeing 2 HDDs out of 4 - the ones that it no longer sees are attached to Intel Corporation C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit (8086:1d6b, isci kernel module). When I boot back into 5.4.0-65-generic, then things are back to normal (after a 2-hour RAID re-sync and fsck :( ). Here is how things look with 5.4.0 (not brave enough to try booting into 5.8 again just yet):

```
$ sudo lsscsi -v
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1001FALS-0 0K05  /dev/sda 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/host2/port-2:0/end_device-2:0/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0]
[2:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1001FALS-0 0K05  /dev/sdb 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:1:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/host2/port-2:1/end_device-2:1/target2:0:1/2:0:1:0]
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDS72101 A41A  /dev/sdc 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/3:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0]
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDS72101 A41A  /dev/sdd 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/4:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata4/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0]
[5:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  hp       CDDVDW SH-216ALN HA5A  /dev/sr0 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/5:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata5/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0]
list_ndevices: scandir: /sys/class/nvme/: No such file or directory
NVMe module may not be loaded

$ sudo lspci -v  -s 0000:02:00.0 -nn
02:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller [0107]: Intel Corporation C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit [8086:1d6b] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit [103c:1589]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at da87c000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at da400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4M]
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Capabilities: [98] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [c4] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=2 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [138] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        Capabilities: [180] Transaction Processing Hints
        Capabilities: [140] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        Kernel driver in use: isci
        Kernel modules: isci
$ sudo lspci -v  -s 0000:00:1f.2 -nn
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller [8086:2826] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller [103c:1589]
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
        I/O ports at e0f0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at e0e0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at e0d0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at e0c0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at e020 [size=32]
        Memory at df348000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
```

With kernel 5.8, the Hitachi drives are there, but the WDC ones are not...

How do I make things work with the new kernels? I updated my grub config to use old 5.4.0 kernel by default, but this does not seem like a good long-term approach...

Comment: Till the next kernel it seems it will have to be the way to go. You are not alone in this.

Comment: Why not just use the GA kernels? (ie. 5.4 kernels are supported the life of 20.04, so why not just use those?)